# Emails are not reaching in microsoft azure hosted website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-website-hosting

We have hosted our website on the Microsoft Azure platform. We created a new contact us form.
From the contact us form, the mails are not reaching the mail id it is directed to after uploading our site. We have tested it from our test-site and it is working.  However, from the azure site, it is not. We have done the PHP coding for the contact us page.

Comment: are you seeing any error? Did you check SPAM? which e-mail provider are you using? Can you check the SMTP Server IP details? Is it a public IP Address that can be used anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended and supported method to send email in Azure (including app services and Azure Functions) is using an Azure Relay such as O365 or Sendgrid.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity